# Direct-Mapped Cache Hit & Miss

Tags: caching, memory, binary, hit

4-bit address

tag 1-bit

index 2-bit

offset 1-bit

2 bytes per block

4 sets (1 block per set)

I am trying to determine if the following addresses are hits or misses. I am presenting the information I have acquired thus far.
(all credit will be given to stack overflow)

Addresses

14

set 3

v = 0

tag = 1

offset = 0

9

set 0

v = 0

tag = 1

offset = 1

2

set 1

v = 0

tag = 0

offset = 0

6

set 3

v = 1

tag = 0

offset = 0

3

set 1

v = 1

tag = 0

offset = 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it's a direct mapped cache, and it has 4 sets, this means that it has a capacity for 4 blocks.

1) Address 14 which in binary is: 1110

Assuming that in the beginning the cache is empty, we got a miss and we store this word on the cache. Tag 1, at set #3.

2) Address 9 which in binary is: 1001

Tag 1 , Set #0, we got a miss. Therefore we store it on set 0.

3) Address 2 in binary; 0010

this block goes on set 1 and it's empty. We got a miss and store it. With the tag 0

4) Address 6 in binary: 0110
As we already have stored a block in set 3, we compare it. As their tags are different Tag 0 != Tag 1 we evict the previous one and we store the new one. Miss

5)Address 3 in binary: 0011
this block goes in set 1 and as we already had a block in set 1 we compare it.
As their tags are equal 0 = 0, we got a HIT.